# Fourier transform of multiple rows

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I want to take FFT of 10 measurements. That means I have 10 rows in my data with each row having dimension [1*2000]. In the code below, I am doing in a wrong way. Can anybody tell me what mistake I am making?

```
load('fb2010');                                   % loading the data
x = fb2010(3:1:15,:);
y_filt = filter(b,a,x);                           % filtering the received signal
%%%%%%%  Fourier transform
nfft = length(y_filt);
for i = 1:10
res(i,:) = fft(y_filt(i,:),nfft)/ nfft;         %%%% Taking first fft and normalizing it
end
res2 = res(:,1:nfft/2+1);                   %%%% taking single sided spectrum
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);            % choosing correct frequency axes
figure, plot(f,abs(res2));
```

Comment: What is wrong now with your code?

Comment: it 's giving incorrect fft. By using this for loop, some of the rows having correct fft while some of them having wrong fft results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `filter` applies the transfer function along the first dimension by default. So you filter your columns instead of your rows. To get the correct result, use the following line:

```
filter(b,a,x,[],2);
```

Then you can omit the loop by using `fft` with a third argument to specify the dimension it operates along. This would be the following line:

```
res = fft(y_filt,nfft,2);
```

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks Matt :D. I will try as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

`doc fft`:

`Y = fft(X,n,dim)` 
where dim is the dimension. I suppose you want `dim = 2`.
This will get rid of the loop and should work. I just used it myself.

Comment: Why 2? my dimesion of each row is 1*2000 and i am having such 10 rows.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too fast and tired this morning. You are right, the fft works, it's the filter that is giving the problem. Still, this `dim` argument will save you from using the loop. See Matt's answer!